# cloud system storage design

Tags: cloud, distributed-computing

I'm developing an web app where some kind of graphics manipulation is required. So user can upload a picture and processing can be done at the backend and feed back to the user.

Right now, the uploaded picture is stored on the local disk in the app server and the path is stored in mysql. Because the image processing is done using imagemagick, local file access is a must. This way works fine but apparently violates principle of distribution system. If the processing is done by a different node than the one that's uploaded, it'll not be able to find the actual image file.

I don't think I should store the image as blob inside mysql. What's a clean way of handling this?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud storage services provide a solution. Upload the picture e.g. to some Azure blob storage or to Amazon Simple Storage Service. Then send the image processing request to your app server passing a link to the image in the cloud. If necessary your app server could download the picture from cloud storage to local server storage as well. But with this approach, you might operate several instances of your service (e.g. several servers) and each might find the image in the cloud and operate on the data. So you are better prepared to scale out your service.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick is perfectly able to access non-local files.

```
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h1iJ.png -verbose info:

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h1iJ.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 260x180+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Palette
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8/1-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 1-bit
    green: 1-bit
    blue: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 46800
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
```

Alternatively, if all the *nodes* are together on the same network, you could use an NFS server, or a NAS to store the files yet make them accessible to all nodes.